# How usin ng-options I can show list with more values and whan selected one to show only one value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have one question  about using ng-options. Is there option to  make it like on the  Image.. In the dropdown to show all the option with values like City,Country,(city code)...
and when we select one of the given option , to show just the city code(LV)???
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJjkv.png)

Thanks to all in advance :)

Comment: yes it is possible. What have you tried so far show us your code. Create a working example of the problem you are facing.

Comment: This is my code to show the data for the drop down.
Index.html
<code>
</code>

Comment: <code>
<select name="location"
                                    id="select-location"
                                    ng-model="selectedLocation"
                                    ng-options="location as location.city_name+' - '+location.city_code for location in mainController.benefitsLocation | orderBy:'id'"
                                    ng-change="mainController.locationChanged()">
                            </select>
</code>

I will create one example  and post it so You can see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use `value` or `ng-value`with required key

```
<code>
<select name="location" id="select-location" ng-model="selectedLocation" ng-options="location as location.city_name+' - '+location.city_code for location in mainController.benefitsLocation | orderBy:'id'" ng-change="mainController.locationChanged()" value="{{location.city_name}}"> </select>
</code>
```

Comment: Hi @Sachin Dongre
I try your example  but it's the same  :(